# Need help solving this code puzzle. Possible binary?

Tags: calculation-puzzle, puzzle-identification

Me and a friend are trying to solve a series of puzzles, and this is the last one I need to solve and I'm stumped.  It's a Christmas themed puzzle titled 'bLitZEN'.  The only hints given are that the title is important and BIT=1011000.

The puzzle reads:

BLT - BIT

IE

BEN - LIZ

IN - TEN

LIEN - LIE

IT - (EN + ZEN)

ZN

When  I first saw it, I assumed it used ASCII but that's not giving me anything.  I don't know anything about binary, so I thought that maybe it might be binary.  But I can't figure out how BIT = 1011000 at all, and I can't seem to use that alone to solve the puzzle.  Typically, each line gives you a single letter, where each line's letter forms a random word.  It's part of a series, so that's what the others were like.

Let me know if you can come up with anything.  Thanks for the help.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

BIT = 1011000 and the mathematical equations makes this look a lot like binary is involved. Combine that with the hint that the title is important, and we can work out where BIT=1011000 comes from:

> Finding the letters BIT in the title gives b-it--- ... the same pattern as 1011000

Knowing that, we can then convert all of the other equations to binary:

> 11001000 - 1011000, 10010, 1000011 - 110100, 10001 - 1011, 110011 - 110010, 11000 - (11 + 111), 101

Solve those, and we get a list of numbers:

> 16 18 15 6 1 14 5

Numbers <= 26 can be converted to letters by counting through the alphabet, giving us:

> PROFANE

Comment: How is your solution Christmas themed?

Comment: @MichaelMcGriff The question only stated that the puzzle was Christmas themed. "Typically, each line gives you a single letter, where each line's letter forms a random word."

Comment: @Otaia I read that to mean the answer would be Christmas themed as well.  We'll just have to wait and see if/when an answer gets accepted.  Though I also read into the question that the OP doesn't know the answer...

Answer (score 1):

As Toby explained

> 1011000 is the bit wise or binary representation of curresponding letters (here for the clue BIT) present in the title.

Following the same rule we get

> (1100100-1011000) (10010) (1000011-110100) (10001-1011) (110011-110010) (11000-(11+111)) (11000-1010) (101)

Which gives

> 1100, 10010, 1111, 110, 1, 1110, 101 => 12, 18, 15, 6, 1, 14, 5

Considering these are the numerical representation of alphabets we get

> L, R, O, F, A, N, E

I assume this is an anagram. On further research I understood its the anagram of

> FAR NOEL (Noel means Christmas or birth of Christ)

Which is definitely Christmas related and referring to the birth of Jesus Christ for the three wise men from far. I also suspect it may related to a Christmas carol that I have heard a long ago.

Comment: Your first one I think is wrong, 1100100 would equate to BLZ and not BLT. Also Noel is french for christmas, but far doesn't say anything.